# Se puede usar tailwindcss sin npm run watch?

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando tailwindcss con laravel mix pero me incomoda tener que estar usando npm run watch cada vez que hago un cambio, hay alguna forma de poder ver los cambios sin ese comando??

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
    
        
    
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        @livewireStyles

        //Script CDN Tailwindcss
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


    </head>
```

Asi esta mi codigo layout

Comment: Hola, no es posible ver cambios a menos que compiles los archivos, cada cambio que haces afecta los bunldle de salida, puedes dejar npm run dev y cuando tengas cambios significativos volver a compilar

Answer (score 0):

En la nueva versión de Tailwindcss te permite añadir un script en su `head`

`<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`

[Tailwind Play CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn). Echale un vistazo a la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwindcss tiene una guia específicamente para Laravel [Te la dejo aquí](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel).

Con respecto a tu código tienes que cambiar:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Por

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

En tu terminal ejecutar:

```sh
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
```

Luego en el archivo *webpack.mix.js* agregar `require("tailwindcss")`

```js
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [
    require("tailwindcss"),
  ]);
```

Luego en el archivo `tailwind.config.js` *"se tuvo que crear al ejecturar `npx tailwindcss init`"* agregar 3 lineas, al final quedará así:

```json
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Por ultimo tienes que agregar en el archivo `/resources/css/app.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Y para que detecte los cambios ejecuta en tu terminal:

```
npm run watch
```

Con eso ya se deberá mostrar bien los cambios y actualizar!